Address in heap bin seems to miss lower 12 bits, why?
I currently try to understand the internals of heap memory management by the libc and I stumbled over a behaviour I can't explain.
I have this very sophisticated program:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gnu/libc-version.h>

int main() {
    uint64_t *ptr = malloc(0x20);

    memset(ptr, 0x55, 0x20);

    free(ptr);

    printf("%lx\n",ptr);
    printf("%lx\n",*ptr);
    puts (gnu_get_libc_version ());

    fgetc(stdin);

    return 0;
}

When I run the program I get the following output:
6068ba91e2a0
6068ba91e
2.39

I actually thought I would find a 64bit address, that would assemble a forward pointer of the heap struct.
It seems the actual output is missing the lower 12 bits.
I can confirm this in gdb:
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── threads ────
[#0] Id 1, Name: "test", stopped 0x79cd7111ba61 in __GI___libc_read (), reason: SIGINT
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── trace ────
[#0] 0x79cd7111ba61 → __GI___libc_read(fd=0x0, buf=0x6068ba91e6e0, nbytes=0x400)
[#1] 0x79cd71092795 → _IO_new_file_underflow(fp=0x79cd712038e0 <_IO_2_1_stdin_>)
[#2] 0x79cd710955c2 → __GI__IO_default_uflow(fp=0x79cd712038e0 <_IO_2_1_stdin_>)
[#3] 0x6068acf781c7 → main()
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
gef➤  x/10gx 0x6068ba91e2a0
0x6068ba91e2a0: 0x00000006068ba91e      0x24c2c355acc8d4bb
0x6068ba91e2b0: 0x5555555555555555      0x5555555555555555
0x6068ba91e2c0: 0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000411
0x6068ba91e2d0: 0x3139616238363036      0x0000000a30610a65
0x6068ba91e2e0: 0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000000
gef➤  heap bin
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── Tcachebins for thread 1 ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Tcachebins[idx=1, size=0x30, count=1] ←  Chunk(addr=0x6068ba91e2a0, size=0x30, flags=PREV_INUSE | IS_MMAPPED | NON_MAIN_ARENA) 
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── Fastbins for arena at 0x79cd71203ac0 ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Fastbins[idx=0, size=0x20] 0x00
Fastbins[idx=1, size=0x30] 0x00
Fastbins[idx=2, size=0x40] 0x00
Fastbins[idx=3, size=0x50] 0x00
Fastbins[idx=4, size=0x60] 0x00
Fastbins[idx=5, size=0x70] 0x00
Fastbins[idx=6, size=0x80] 0x00
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── Unsorted Bin for arena at 0x79cd71203ac0 ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[+] Found 0 chunks in unsorted bin.
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── Small Bins for arena at 0x79cd71203ac0 ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[+] Found 0 chunks in 0 small non-empty bins.
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── Large Bins for arena at 0x79cd71203ac0 ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[+] Found 0 chunks in 0 large non-empty bins.
gef➤ 

The free'd chunk got moved to tCache.
Why are the lower 12 bits missing or does tCache (and fastbin) behave differently?
My system is Kubuntu 24.04.1, glibc 2.39.

EDIT:
I'm aware that one should not use the pointer after free, but this is not my intention. I want to learn about the internals of heap allocation, since I got assigned a task in university where I need to analyze a program. There i stumbled over this behavior and I was not able to explain it.

EDIT:
I have found the responsible code in the libc:
/* Safe-Linking:
   Use randomness from ASLR (mmap_base) to protect single-linked lists
   of Fast-Bins and TCache.  That is, mask the "next" pointers of the
   lists' chunks, and also perform allocation alignment checks on them.
   This mechanism reduces the risk of pointer hijacking, as was done with
   Safe-Unlinking in the double-linked lists of Small-Bins.
   It assumes a minimum page size of 4096 bytes (12 bits).  Systems with
   larger pages provide less entropy, although the pointer mangling
   still works.  */
#define PROTECT_PTR(pos, ptr) \
  ((__typeof (ptr)) ((((size_t) pos) >> 12) ^ ((size_t) ptr)))
#define REVEAL_PTR(ptr)  PROTECT_PTR (&ptr, ptr)

[...]

/* Caller must ensure that we know tc_idx is valid and there's room
   for more chunks.  */
static __always_inline void
tcache_put (mchunkptr chunk, size_t tc_idx)
{
  tcache_entry *e = (tcache_entry *) chunk2mem (chunk);

  /* Mark this chunk as "in the tcache" so the test in _int_free will
     detect a double free.  */
  e->key = tcache_key;

  e->next = PROTECT_PTR (&e->next, tcache->entries[tc_idx]);
  tcache->entries[tc_idx] = e;
  ++(tcache->counts[tc_idx]);
}

Now I know at least where it comes from.
For the people down-voting:
Programming does not end with the C/C++ specification. There is also programm Code behind the magic curtains of libc. :)

You cannot use *ptr after the call to free.

I'm aware of this, it's not about using it, it's about learning about the internals of memory management.

But when you invoke "undefined behavior", the result is undefined - anything can happen. Perhaps free reuses some of the bits, we don't know.

free is assigning it to the heap bin, this is not undefined. When I use a larger allocation and it gets not assigned to fastbin or tCache, the result is as expected. But it's not when free assigns it to fastbin or tCache.

Yes I do. But again, the implementation of free is not magic and when the documentation states undefined behaviour this is meant for the programmers to not use the pointer any further. But the operation system, or specifically the malloc and free methods are using data structures inside the heap to manage memory. I want to understand why the pointer stored here seems incomplete, from my understanding.

12 bits correspond to 4kiB. Maybe it is the number of some 4kiB page and not an address.

I have already found the culprit, it's some pointer protection directly in the libc.  See my last edit. I did not understand how it works, but at least I could find now why the pointer looks that odd.

I didn't vote, but for future questions it could be a good idea to state the system specific parts of the question up front. Otherwise some of us might think that tags c and free is about what the C language says about the free function.  :-)

Oh, and also, if you have found an answer to the question, you can write that as an actual answer so others can see that there is an answer. You even get a badge for self-answering!

Fair enough, that's understandable. What tags would be feasible instead? I thought the terms heap and tCache, as well as my first edit would bring clarity to the question.

I will answer it, as soon as I understood the whole thing, until now I just know the location bit not the mechanism. But thanks :)

printf("%lx\n",ptr); printf("%lx\n",*ptr); are not using specified correct formats.  Even if it works for OP, better to use correct matching ones as not to be a distraction.

for printf("%lx\n",ptr); i agree, but printf("%lx\n",*ptr); should be good no?

For uint64_t it may or may not be correct to use %lx. An unsigned long may only be 32 bits and you will need %llx then. Therefore just use PRIx64 instead from stdint.h.

Ah thanks for that, didn't know this existed
